# Wpf button won't hide after resolving action

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this piece of markup in datagrid for button.

```xaml
<DataTemplate x:Key="acceptingTextOnBtn">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button
                x:Name="ItemButton"
                Grid.Column="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.AcceptBtnCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCDeliveryDetail}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.SelectedOneWeighing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCDeliveryDetail}}"
                Content="Schválit"
                Style="{StaticResource DialogButton}"
                Visibility="{Binding WeighingType, Converter={StaticResource IsControlWeighToVisibility}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Button
                x:Name="ItemButtonStorno"
                Grid.Column="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.ResetWeighingBtnCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCDeliveryDetail}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.SelectedOneWeighing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCDeliveryDetail}}"
                Content="Stornovat"
                Style="{StaticResource DialogButton}"
                Visibility="{Binding CanBeCancelled, Converter={StaticResource IsWeightResetToVisibility}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

After I click on the button I want to immediately hide this button. I wrote a converter for that, but it doesn't work.

**Converter for Accept Button:**

```
    public class IsControlWeighingToVisibility : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var info = value as string;                  

            if (System.Convert.ToInt32(info) == (int)WeighingType.CheckWeighingWithSAP)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }         

            if(info == WeighingType.CheckWeighingWithSAP.ToString())
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }

            else
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Converter for cancel button:**

```
 public class IsWeightResetToVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            bool info = Boolean.Parse(value.ToString());

            if (!info)
                return Visibility.Collapsed;

            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `CanBeCancelled` - what is it? Does it in correct context?

Comment: are you sure you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel?

Comment: CanBeCancelled is correct. Because there are two states for button. One is accept and one if user want to cancel.

Comment: @tabby i dont want to disable button, but hide it completely

Comment: `CanBeCancelled` is static field?

Comment: @JohnyL Can be cancelled is bindend from entity. Thats fine.

Comment: @DanielCapek Then show your converter

Comment: @JohnyL i posted answer, check it out :) there are converters

Comment: @DanielCapek You should alter your original question instead. :)

Comment: Why the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay` on the visibility binding? Shouldn't this be a one-way information flowing from your viewmodel into the converter & button?

Comment: @grek40 Without this it doesn´t work also.

Comment: it just doesn't have any sense

Comment: What type has `CanBeCancelled`? is it bool?

Comment: @Foggy finder yes it is bool :)

Comment: well, then use standard converter - `Visibility="{Binding CanBeCancelled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}`

Comment: `<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>`

Comment: btw, just a note. There is [SO WPF chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) - it is a really good place .

Comment: @FoggyFinder its nice, but i need reputation 20 to chat with you :D

Comment: @FoggyFinder booltovis doesn´t work immedieately also .. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161084/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-daniel-capek).

Comment: What type of property is WeighingType and how and where do you set WeighingType and CanBeCancelled?